# Multiple queues in same Module with only one connection factory in weblogic and spring JMS template

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, weblogic12c, spring-jms

I'm new with JMS and queues. Please excuse my knowledge.

Server : Weblogic 12.x
Frameworks: Spring, Hibernate, Spring JMS with JMSTemplate.

I have a business case where a scheduler wakes up for every X mins and processes the records and pushes them into queue. In fact, we have 2 schedulers doing the same but for diff tables. So, for this case, I have implemented a no xml approach(fully annotated) for JMS template. I have setup a single module in weblogic with a connection factory and 2 queues. I have tested it and its working fine.

However,

1. Is this a good approach to use 2 queues with a single conn factory?
2. In the QueueMessageSender, I am using the below annotations to send the message.

   ```
       @Autowired
           private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate_Queue_1;
           @Autowired
           private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate_Queue_2;

           jmsTemplate_Queue_1.send(wrapMessage("Hello"));
           jmsTemplate_Queue_1.send(wrapMessage("test"));

   private MessageCreator wrapMessage(final String msg) {
           return new MessageCreator() {
               @Override
               public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                   ObjectMessage om = session.createObjectMessage();
                   om.setObject(msg);                
                   return om;
               }
           };
   }
   ```

Is this the right way to do it?
In future what possible problems can I run into if this is not a right approach.

Any suggestions on this topic could be helpful to me.Any good books you can suggest for JMS with spring with an example based approach would be great!

Here is the config file in java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ComponentScan({ "com.xxxx.xxx.config" })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class JmsConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
        JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        Properties jndiProps = new Properties();

        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        Properties props = System.getProperties() ;
        jndiProps.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url","t3://localhost:7001"); 
        jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(jndiProps);
        return jndiTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean jmsConnectionFactory() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();

        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(environment.getProperty("jms.connectionFactory"));

        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean queue_one() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();

        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(environment.getProperty("jms.queue_one")); 
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean queue_two() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();

        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(environment.getProperty("queue_two")); 
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy connectionFactoryProxy() {
        return new TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy((ConnectionFactory) jmsConnectionFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean(name="jmsTemplate_Queue_1")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate_Queue_1() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactoryProxy());

        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination((Destination) queue_one().getObject());

        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name="jmsTemplate_Queue_2")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate_Queue_2() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactoryProxy());

        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination((Destination) queue_two().getObject());

        return jmsTemplate;
    }
    //Thank you for looking the code till here. I don't want to be rude by not saying thank you! 
    @Bean
    public QueueMessageSender queueMessageSender() {        
        return  new QueueMessageSender();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is fine; since they both use the same connection factory, you could use a single `JmsTemplate` and pass in the destination on each send, but there's no compelling reason to do so with only two queues. If you had lots of queues, it might be easier to manage.

However, there is no such method...

```
jmsTemplate_Queue_1.send("Hello");
```

... I presume you mean

```
jmsTemplate_Queue_1.convertAndSend("Hello");
```

...since the String has to be converted to a JMS Message.

Comment: My mistake Sir. I have edited the message section with one more method.

Comment: Also, can you suggest a nice book for newbies on JMS and queue / topic messaging with spring.  Is JMS setup and configuration specific to servers like weblogic/Jboss etc?

Comment: The chapter in the [Spring Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html) should have most of what you need. Yes, setting up the broker is vendor-dependent but, typically, from a Spring configuration perspective, it just means different class names for `Destination` (queues/topics) and connection factory bean definitions, or the use of JNDI to get them from the server. This makes it very easy to use the same Spring application with different brokers. For example, an embedded ActiveMQ broker is often used for CI integration tests.

Comment: You might want to consider using the `convertAndSend` method(s). That way, a `String` is sent as a `TextMessage`. Always sending `ObjectMessage` is not necessarily the best thing to do.